# Efficient way to update MySql table by expanding fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mysql-python

I want to expand my tweets (Twitter) database. This database contains an id INT, created_at DATETIME, and json TEXT fields.  I want to update my database as follows. I want to add 2 extra columns named user_id and coordinates that should be extracted from the json part.

My idea is to write a python script and to update the database line by line. However, this approach sounds to me a little bad. This is because for every row, I need to read it with python, to parse it and then to update the table. Is there a more clever way of doing that using MYSQL functions?

My Database has rows for 3 months with approximately 10000 rows per day as a result 1M rows.

I have a primary index on id, and a BTREE index on DATETIME, the table is partitioned in 30 tables.

Also I noted that when I do one by one inserts in the DB from python is much much slower than the time required to load a csv file. And this is why I want again to avoid python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no elegant way to parse JSON in a stored procedure. You might be able to come up with some kind of kludge that would pull the items you need using string functions. But that sounds nasty and unreliable.

### Creating a table for metadata

In my experience, a good way to handle this kind of expansion operation is to add a new table rather than to try to add columns to the existing table.

Your new table, let's call it `metadata`, will have these columns:

```
id          PK, also FK to tweet table.  NOT autoincrement.
created_at  copied over from tweet table.  
user_id     the value of the user_id you extract.
lat         FLOAT value for coordinate, NULL if no coordinate was available
lon         FLOAT value or NULL like LAT.
```

You can probably partition your `metadata` table the same way you partitioned your tweet table. That's why I copied the `created_at` field in this design.

### Populating the metadata table

Then you can run a background client program (in python or whatever language suits you) that will populate this table. It will read the rows from the tweets table and then insert corresponding rows here. You probably can do this in batches of 100 rows or so and make it reasonably quick.

If I were you I'd use a query like this to retrieve each batch of tweets to update.

```
SELECT tweet.id, tweet.created_at, tweet.json
  FROM tweet
  LEFT JOIN metadata ON tweet.id = metadata.id
 WHERE metadata.id IS NULL
 LIMIT 100
```

This will fetch 100 rows (exactly which rows> that's formally unpredictable, but that's OK) that don't already have corresponding rows in `metadata`.

Then, extract the metadata and INSERT the rows you need. Notice that INSERTs are much faster than UPDATEs in many cases. Also, you can do a multirow INSERT using a query with this pattern:

```
 INSERT INTO metadata (id, created_id, user_id, lat, long)  VALUES
 (?,?,?,?,?),
 (?,?,?,?,?),
 (?,?,?,?,?),
 (?,?,?,?,?),
 (?,?,?,?,?)
```

This multi-row INSERT makes things faster by reducing server round trips.

You can simply loop these 100-row batches until the query gets no more rows. This program will probably run for many hour to handle your megarow, but that's OK. With this batching strategy you can restart it at any time and it will take up where it left off.

You can even leave it running to populate new metadata as new tweets arrive if you want.

Notice that it's NOT set up to have more than one instance of the update program running. You'll need to do something with transactions if you want that. IMO it's not worth the trouble.

### Using the metadata

When you need to use the metadata you can use queries like this:

```
 SELECT tweet.whatever, tweet.whatever, 
        metadata.user_id, metadata.lat, metadata.lon
   FROM tweet
   LEFT JOIN metadata ON tweet.id = metadata.id
  WHERE tweet.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Notice that I use a `LEFT JOIN` rather than a JOIN so you'll still get rows from `tweet` even when the job populating metadata isn't done yet.

You can also change the software inserting new tweets so it will insert metadata correctly.